# python chat with sockets using select model

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

Hey I'm trying to build a multi-user chat with python but I have a problem with the select command.

this is the client :

```
import socket
import select
import msvcrt
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 23))
messages = []

while True:
    rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(client_socket, client_socket, [])
    for current_socket in rlist:
        data = current_socket.recv(1024)
        print data
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        word = raw_input()
        client_socket.send(word)
```

i'm pretty sure that the problem is in this line - **rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(client_socket, client_socket, [])**

and this is the server:

```
import socket , select

server_socket= socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0',23))
server_socket.listen(5)
open_client_sockets = []
messages_to_send = []

def send_wating_messages(wlist):
    for message in messages_to_send:
        (client_socket,data) = message
        for client_socket in wlist:
            client_socket.send(data)
        messages_to_send.remove(message)


while True:
    rlist,wlist,xlist = select.select([server_socket]+open_client_sockets,open_client_sockets,[])
    for current_socket in rlist:
        if current_socket is server_socket:
            (new_socket,address) = server_socket.accept()
            open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
        else:
            data = current_socket.recv(1024)
            if data=="":
                open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                print 'Connection with client closed.'

            else:
                messages_to_send.append(data)

    send_wating_messages(wlist)
```

the server is well functioning but the client doesn't work.

Comment: [select.select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) accepts __sequences__ of waitable objects (e.g. _sockets_). So your remark is right, the client code should be changed to: `rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([client_socket], [client_socket], [])`.

Comment: thanks , problem is solved

Comment: Also, it seems that the client implements incorrect logic. It should wait for two possible source of events - user input from the keyboard and server messages, and then process those events.

Comment: right now it will be blocked on raw_input

Comment: what do you suggest ? @user3159253

Comment: Well, the basic problem is that you use Windows :) MS Windows doesn't support `select` on objects other than sockets (in unix-like systems one can wait on pipes etc, so waiting for any number of possible input sources is the same as in the server case). if you don't wish to go multithreading, I'd implement the following logic: first, `select` on the socket for input data a limited period of time (say a second), then in a cycle while user input is available,  read it using a char oriented function like `msvcrt.getch()`, then if you got something to send, `select` the socket for writing and etc

Comment: but msvcrt.getch() get only one char and i want to get a sentence  @user3159253

Comment: Indeed. But raw_input() blocks your input forever (until `\n`). So you have to read the input in a non-blocking manner. I'm preparing an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's not an entire answer but rather an example of a non-blocking client. I can't test it right now because I don't have MS Windows available, but you'll get the idea

```
# here and below assume that strings are byte-oriented strings.
# In Python 3, where strings are char-oriented, `str.encode()` and `str.decode()` might be in use

def msw_nonblocking_raw_input(limit=100):
    collected = ''
    for i in range(1, limit): # don't let a user block the program by pressing a key permanently
         if not msvcrt.kbhit():
             break
         collected += msvcrt.getche()
    logging.debug('user input [%s]' % collected)
    return collected

def socket_nonblocking_input(sock):
    try:
         msg = sock.recv(4096)
    except socket.error as e:
        err = e.args[0]
        if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            return ''
        else:
            # a "real" error occurred
            raise
    # got the message. If it's empty, EOF occured
    logging.debug('server sent us [%s]' % msg)
    if not msg:
        sys.exit(0) # perhaps a more graceful shutdown is required...
    return msg

def socket_nonblocking_output(sock, msg):
    try:
        res = sock.send(msg)
    except socket.error as e:
        err = e.args[0]
        if err == errno.EAGAIN or err == errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
            return msg
        else:
            # a "real" error occurred
            raise
    # If res is 0, then EOF occured
    if not res:
        sys.exit(0) # perhaps a more graceful shutdown is required...
    logging.debug("we have sent %d bytes out of %d" % (res, len(msg)))
    return msg[res:] # return the unsent tail of the message

# the main cycle
data_read = ''
data_to_write = ''
timeout = 1.000 # 1 second
client_socket.setblocking(0) # put the socket into the non-blocking mode
while True:
    sockets_to_write = (client_socket,) if data_to_write else ()
    (to_read, to_write, exceptional) = select((client_socket,), sockets_to_write, (), timeout)
    if to_read:
        data_read = socket_nonblocking_input(to_read[0])
        # technically sys.stdout could also block (e.g. being piped or simply in a slow terminal) but for the sake of simplicity, don't bother ourselves.
        if data_read:
            sys.stdout.write(data_read)
    if to_write:
        data_to_write = socket_nonblocking_output(to_write[0], data_to_write)

    data_to_write += msw_nonblocking_raw_input()
```

Again, I'm not sure that the code is 100% correct, I haven't tested it, even for syntax errors, I don't have MS Windows right now. But I'm sure you can get the idea. If there're some troubles don't hesitate to ask.